Suggestion for how to control the logic flow to short circuit or run all logic anyway
I am writing in Java and I had a existing code that have bunch of condition checking. The method will return immediately if one of the condition is fail. The existing code looks like this
public Reason checkCondition(){
    if (! matchConditionA()) {
        return new Reason("Condition A", false);
    }

    if (! matchConditionB()) {
        return new Reason("Condition B", false);
    }

    if (! matchConditionC()) {
        return new Reason("Condition C", false);
    }

    return new Reason("Match all", true);
}

I would like to add a boolean flag to control the flow of logic checking. Whenever the flag is true, I would like to run all the condition checking any way and return a set of failing reason. The following code is something I can think of.
public List<Reason> checkCondition(String paramA, boolean runAll){
    List<Reason> result = new ArrayList<Reason>();
    if (! matchConditionA()) {
        result.add(new Reason("Condition A", false));
        if (!runAll) {
            return result;
        }
        
    }

    if (! matchConditionB()) {
        result.add(new Reason("Condition B", false));
        if (!runAll) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    if (! matchConditionC()) {
        result.add(new Reason("Condition C", false));
        if (!runAll) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

My question is, are there any better way , or design pattern I could use, to reduce the additional if (!runAll) in all the existing if block?

you could have a Condition interface or class, with a method for testing, returning the Result; the instances of that would be in a List and code would iterate over that list eventually collecting the results or stopping at first fail
